# Can laser pointers defend you from wild cats?

Tags: substitute-tool, camping

As I'm sure many are aware, laser pointers work great for distracting house cats and even some dogs to the point of insanity.

Does this have the same effect on larger wild cats? Would a laser pointer be an effective survival tool when faced with mountain lions or other wild cats?

Comment: Welcome to Lifehacks SE. I'm going to have to close this question as off-topic because it does not seem to be about an actual problem. Sorry :(

Comment: As a last resort you could maybe point the laser directly in their eyes to blind them but I'm not sure if that is allowed but I guess it's better than dying.

Answer (score 2):

Setting aside for the moment the (somewhat ridiculous) issue of whether a cheetah, leopard or the like that plans to attack and eat you could be **distracted** into not doing so, especially by something as small as the dot of a laser pointer, no, **this will not work**. Laser pointers distract house pets because they make a small bright dot on a smooth surface like a floor or wall. A wild cat who plans to attack you will doubtless do so in a much more heterogeneous environment, like a jungle trail, where one little spot of light moving around will really mean nothing to them.

Besides, if a wild cat intends to eat you, you won't know until its teeth are in the back of your neck. Watch your pet house cat attack that toy mouse you give it, or stalk a bird in the backyard. Your opportunities for interaction before you are pounced on simply do not exist.